# Show more X-Values in Linechart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm new at this lib. I've created a `Linechart` and added a few `Entries`. Chart only displays two of them, also can't zoom in/out or scroll to the chart.

Can someone help me?

Comment: What have you tried? Could you provide some code examples. Hard to help going off nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment.. could you post your solution maybe?

edit: Meanwhile I've figured it out.

```
 XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
 xAxis.setAdjustXLabels(false);
```

This will show all labels.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Edited, added answer. Also, it sucks that there is no other way for me to communicate with the poster.

Comment: Just mention them by typing @Tamas and if they log in they will see a notification. Whether it's clicked or not... another story!